# How to remove old data rect from d3 chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

### ChartWrapper:

This is the first time I am posting a question. My apology if I miss something. Thanks in advance. My problem is I am receiving the updated data from api call based on some selection and passing into the
CharWrapper component, which in turn call a updated() method in D3Chart class to populate the d3 chart
with the updated data. But, on first call the chart is populating correctly but on the second selection
when I get the updated data from api response, chart remain as it is, with the old values. It is not
getting updated

```
 export default class ChartWrapper extends React.Component {
  
     componentDidMount() {
        this.tooltipRef = React.createRef();
        this.mySvgRef = React.createRef();
        this.legendRef = React.createRef();
        this.setState({ chart: new D3Chart(this.refs.svgChart, this.refs.tooltip, this.refs.legends) });
     }
          shouldComponentUpdate() {
        console.log("shouldComponentUpdate")
        return false;
    }
        static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
            if (prevState) {

              prevState.chart.update(nextProps.chartdata);
              console.log("getDerivedStateFromProps : ", nextProps.chartdata)
              return { chartdata: nextProps.chartdata }
         }

          return null;
      }
       render() {
           return (<div>
            <div className="svg" ref="svgChart"></div>
            <div className="tag" ref="tooltip"></div>
            <div className="legend" ref="legends">
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
}
```

D3Chart Component code :

Below is my D3chart component. I have using it with react. Why the older data still on the window, after calling the exit().remove() on the data selection as well. I am struggling from the past three days. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Note : The code inside the D3Chart class constructor function will execute only once and update() function is getting called as soon I get the updated data as props from api response.

```
      export default class D3Chart {
         constructor(mySvgRef, tooltipRef, legendRef) {
            const vis = this;

            vis.tooltipRef = tooltipRef;
            vis.ganttSvgRef = d3.select(mySvgRef)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("class", "svg")
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

          vis.timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, w - 100]);

          vis.yScale = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, h - margin.top - margin.bottom], 0);

          vis.xAxisGroup = vis.ganttSvgRef.append("g")
            .attr("className", "x top axis")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 20 + ', ' + 0 + ')')

          vis.yAxisGroup = vis.ganttSvgRef.append("g")
            .attr("className", "y axis")
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + 0 + ')')


          vis.legendRef = d3.select(legendRef)
            .style("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + 'px')

          vis.ganttSvgRef.append("text")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + 0 + " ," +
                (h / 2) + ") rotate(-90)")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Vessel in Terminal");

      } 

         update = (chartData) => {
           var barHeight = 50;
           var gap = 95;
           var topPadding = 0;
           var sidePadding = 20;
           const vis = this;
           console.log("I am updated with : ", chartData)
           var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

           var slotNumber = [];
           var vesselsNames = [];
           var serviceName = [];
           var serviceColorSelector = {}
        
         for (var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
               slotNumber.push(chartData[i].slot);
               serviceName.push(chartData[i].serviceName_data);
               vesselsNames.push(chartData[i].vesselName_data);
        }


            var uniqueService = [...new Set(serviceName)];
           for (var i = 0; i < uniqueService.length; i++) {
               serviceColorSelector[uniqueService[i]] = colArray[i];
        }
        slotNumber = this.checkUnique(slotNumber);
        slotNumber.sort(function (a, b) {
            return Number(a) - Number(b);
        });

        vis.timeScale.domain([d3.min(chartData, function (d) { return parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data); }),
        d3.max(chartData, function (d) { return parseTime(d.departureTime_data); })])
        vis.yScale.domain(slotNumber)

        var xAxistop = d3.axisTop(vis.timeScale).ticks().tickSizeInner((-h + margin.top + margin.bottom))
        vis.xAxisGroup
            // .transition()
            .call(xAxistop);

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(vis.yScale)
        vis.yAxisGroup
            // .transition()
            .call(yAxis);
        console.log("vis.ganttSvgRef :", vis.ganttSvgRef)


        if (slotNumber.length > 6) {
            barHeight = this.calculateBarHeight(slotNumber.length, barHeight);
        }
        var rectangles = vis.ganttSvgRef
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(chartData);
        console.log("Reactangles : ", rectangles)
        rectangles.exit().remove();

        var innerRects = rectangles.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)) + sidePadding;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) {
                for (var j = 0; j < slotNumber.length; j++) {
                    if (d.slot == slotNumber[j]) {
                        return vis.yScale(d.slot);
                    }
                }
            })
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return (vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.departureTime_data)) - vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)));
            })
            .attr("height", barHeight)
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                for (var i = 0; i < vesselsNames.length; i++) {
                    return serviceColorSelector[d.serviceName_data]
                }
            })

        innerRects.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            var tag = "";

            tag = "Imo: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].imo_data + "<br/>" +
                "Vessel: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].vesselName_data + "<br/>" +
                "Service: " + d3.select(this).data()[0].serviceName_data;


            var x = (this.x.animVal.value + this.width.animVal.value / 2) + "px";
            var y = this.y.animVal.value + 25 + "px";

            vis.tooltipRef.innerHTML = tag;
            vis.tooltipRef.style.top = y;
            vis.tooltipRef.style.left = x;
            vis.tooltipRef.style.display = "block";
        }).on('mouseout', function () {
            vis.tooltipRef.style.display = "none";

        });


        var legend5 = vis.legendRef.selectAll(".legend5")

            .data(serviceName)

        legend5.exit().remove();
        var p = legend5.enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "legends5").append("p")
            .attr("class", "country-name")
        p.append("span")
            .attr("class", "key-dot")
            .style("background", function (d, i) {
                return serviceColorSelector[d]
            })

        p.insert("text")
            .attr("class", "text-style")
            .style("text-anchor", 'start')

            .text(function (d, i) { return d })

    }

    checkUnique = (arr) => {
        var hash = {}, result = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; ++i) {
            if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) {
                hash[arr[i]] = true;
                result.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    calculateBarHeight = (totalSlot, barheight) => {
        let height = barheight;
        let franction_x = totalSlot - 6;
        let franction_y = 6;
        let decrementRatio = franction_x / (franction_x + franction_y);
        let decresedHeight = decrementRatio * barheight;
        let rectHeight = Math.trunc(barheight - decresedHeight);
        return rectHeight;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
d3.select(mySvgRef).selectAll('svg').remove();
```

before the line

```
d3.select(mySvgRef).append('svg')...
```

Comment: Thanks michael for your suggestion. But what I think is that, since the constructor will execute only once and that will create the svg. If i will remove svg then, there will be no place to populate the updated data for chart, as the whole chart is displayed on svg.

Comment: I nailed it, Actually in d3 V5. you need to use merge() method to update the rect with new data. Above is the code i used

Answer (score 0):

d3 V5 :

I have make the use of merge() method which solve my issue. Hope it help for other also``

```
    ` var rectangles = vis.ganttSvgRef.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(chartData);
   
                       rectangles.exit().remove();

    var innerRects = rectangles.enter().append("rect").merge(rectangles)
                     .attr("x", function (d) {
                     return vis.timeScale(parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data)) + 
                             sidePadding;
        })`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a dashboard having multiple widget showing different d3 charts then use the following code-

```
d3.selectAll("#d3-donutChart > *").remove();
```

this will only clear the specific chart, not all the svg's in the webpage.

Add this line just before redrawing the d3 graph for updated data.